# Best time to buy and sell stocks with multiple buy transactions are allowed and can sell all shares at once

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, network-flow

I've been trying to solve a variation of this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389658/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stocks-when-allowing-consecutive-buys-or-sells

You are given an input array of non-negative integers. You are allowed to either buy 1 share or sell any number of shares that you own, or not make any transaction in each time period. Find the maximum profit you can obtain.

Purchases are negative and sales are positive cash flows. For example, if prices are [3,4,5,3,5,2] the maximum profit can be realized by purchasing a share in each of the first two periods for cash flows -3 + -4 = -7 then selling them both at the 3rd period for 2*5 = 10.

Alternatively, you may purchase a share in 4th period for 3 and sell in 5th period for 5. Total profits are – 3 -4 + 10 -3 + 5 = 5. Another way to the same outcome is to purchase shares in each of 1,2,4th periods for -3 -4 -3 = -10 do nothing at the 2nd period then sell all 3 shares at the 5th period (total 3*5 = 15) for a total profit -10 + 15 = 5.

I've attempted several dynamic programming approaches, but the closest to the solution I found was min-cost flow approach in the link I provided. However, its a slightly different variation as here you are allowed to sell all your shares on a given day.

Its been mentioned in the comments a dynamic programming approach may work, however I cannot find a recursive relationship to even start on the problem. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: "the link I provided" - I don't see a link

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: It seems you copied from your post on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/q/76774147/781723) without copying over the link.  Also, I don't see that this has addressed the feedback that you got there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774147/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stocks-with-multiple-buy-transactions-are-allowed-and#comment135349803_76774147).  See the link I provided for how to make a systematic attempt at finding a dynamic programming algorithm.  Please [edit] your post to address each of these points.

Comment: I've added the link- hyperlink didn't copy over. I've also deleted the duplicate question in SO. I've tried dynamic programming but it doesn't work. I cannot find a recursive relation.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide a self-contained statement of the problem, in a way that can be understood without having to refer to a separate link.  What are the inputs to the algorithm?  What are the limits on acceptable solutions?  Are there multiple stock companies that can be bought/sold?  Is there an initial cash balance, and the cash on hand can never go negative?  etc.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't find any recursive algorithm to solve this problem.  It seems straightforward.  Are you sure you can't find any recursive algorithm at all?  (Don't worry about running time; exponential time is fine.)

Comment: It is self contained. I provided the link to provide more context on solutions I tried. I found that particular problem the closest to what I am trying to solve. The input is an array of integers. The explanation I provided sets this out quite clearly how transactions occur. There is no starting cash balance. Rather, there can be positive and negative cash flows depending on whether shares are bought or sold. There is only a single company's stock represented by the input array. I've added some more info to the question.

Comment: Hint:If the maximum is at time t, then you want to buy everything before time t and sell it all at time t. Now what do you want to do after time t?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Would I want to repeat this process by buying everything up to time t2, which represents the second highest price? What would the termination condition be? Presumably, in some cases that you have leftover days after sales. Would there be a possibility of alternative days on which to sell that are not the highest priced out of remaining days but enable more coverage of leftover days?